# What's the difference between &nbsp and &nbsp;?

Tags: html

What's the difference between the two **`&nbsp; and &nbsp`** if both of them produces the same output?

Thanks!

Comment: @KrishR but i tried it in fiddle and it produced the same output as to  &nbsp;

Comment: using the ";" in all cases to avoid problems with user agents that require this character to be present!!

Comment: Yes Am, for answering your Question.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm just curious on such stuff. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space; use it instead of a normal space between two words that should be rendered on the same line even if word wrapping would normally prevent that.

`&nbsp` is (in HTML 5) an error that you depend on browsers to recover from.

See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references):

> The ampersand must be followed by one of the names given in the named character references section, using the same case. **The name must be one that is terminated by a ";"** (U+003B) character.

The semi-colon is optional, *in some circumstances* (e.g. when followed by a non-name character), in HTML 4.x and earlier.